# How to remove the down icon from button menu of lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-buttonmenu

While creating a Menu using the 'lightning-button-menu' tag by assigning a custom icon I am getting the down icon too beside the actual icon. Can anyone help how to remove that? Adding the screenshot for reference.

[image: image with down icon]

Name
                            
                        
                        
                            
                             
                                    Email
                            
                            
                        
                        
                            More Actions
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                                
                                                
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                                {test.Name}
                                            
                                        
                                        
                                    
                                    
                                        
                                        {test.Email}
                                    
                                     
                                        
                                          
                                          
                                          
                                            
                                              
                                                  
                                                    
                                                        
                                                          
                                                              
                                                          
                                                          Menu Item One
                                                        
                                                    
                                                  
                                                  
                                                    
                                                        
                                                          
                                                              
                                                          
                                                          Menu Item Two
                                                        
                                                    
                                                  
                                                  
                                                    
                                                        
                                                          
                                                              
                                                          
                                                          Menu Item Three

Comment: From your description, `lightning-button-icon` with custom dropdown is more appropriate for this requirement.

Comment: Do you mean the inside button menu? if I use the inside button menu tag it is displaying the ribbon tag and the three dots icon s coming inside of it.

Comment: Nope. Instead of `lightning-button-menu` use `lightning-button-icon` and display dropdown on click of it.

Comment: Will you please mind giving an example for that if possible

Comment: Sure , I'll add an example in some time.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the notch from `lightning-button-menu` is not possible.
I would suggest you to use `lightning-button-icon` instead.
Please use below implementation :

-> **HTML** : Here , we will use a `lightning-button-icon` for toggling the menu items. On each click of `lightning-button-icon` , we will toggle the `menuItems` div.

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <lightning-button-icon
    icon-name="utility:threedots"
    alternative-text="Settings"
    variant="neutral"
    title="Settings"
    onclick={handleClick}>
  </lightning-button-icon>
  <div class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click menuItems">
    <div class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_left slds-dropdown_small">
      <ul class="slds-dropdown__list" role="menu" aria-label="Show More">
          <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation" data-id="Menu Item One" onclick={handleMenuItemClick}>
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="0">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Menu Item One">
                  <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right_x-small" aria-hidden="true">
                      <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#user"></use>
                  </svg>
                  Menu Item One
                </span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation" data-id="Menu Item Two" onclick={handleMenuItemClick}>
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Menu Item Two">
                  <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right_x-small" aria-hidden="true">
                      <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#user"></use>
                  </svg>
                  Menu Item Two
                </span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation" data-id="Menu Item Three" onclick={handleMenuItemClick}>
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">
                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Menu Item Three">
                  <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-m-right_x-small" aria-hidden="true">
                      <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#user"></use>
                  </svg>
                  Menu Item Three
                </span>
            </a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

-> **JS** : Here, we need to handle 2 events -

1st is click of the lightning-button-icon which will just toggle the menu items.

2nd is click of each menu item. We assign a click handler (`handleMenuItemClick`). We use a custom `data-id` attribute for each menu and capture it in JS using `dataset`.

```
handleClick() {
    const menuItems = this.template.querySelector(".menuItems");
      if (menuItems) {
        menuItems.classList.toggle("slds-is-open");
      }
  }

  handleMenuItemClick(event) {
    const dataId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    console.log("dataId ", dataId);
    //do something on click
    const menuItems = this.template.querySelector(".menuItems");
      if (menuItems) {
        menuItems.classList.toggle("slds-is-open");
      }
  }
```

--> **CSS** : Some css for minor adjustment of menu item.

```
.menu-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Reference - https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/menus/

Comment: Hi @Rohit, I tried to implement your code but it is not showing the menu items for all the records it is only showing the menu item for the first record but when I click on the remaining records it is showing the options on the first record again.

Comment: @Developer_SFDC : Above example is for one row . For this issue , you need to add the markup to the question to check. Most probably , you have got some issue while looping over the list of items in markup.

Comment: I am adding the markup at the parent template level and it is displaying the fetched data successfully but for the menu item it is not working. I placed the code inside the <td> of the table body where I am iterating the records

Comment: I can help in a better way if the parent template code is provided in the question. Difficult to troubleshoot without the code.You can edit the question using [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/408359/edit) link.